Seeking Guidance in organizing Microservice folders with Clean Architecture and CQRS Pattern
Greetings fellow developers,
Our team is embarking on the creation of a Billing Microservice, aiming to implement clean architecture with the CQRS pattern. Below, I've outlined our current folder structure. I'm reaching out to seek advice on how we can enhance our folder organization to align better with clean architecture principles, ensuring project maintainability and efficiency
src
├── Core
│   ├── Application.csproj
│   │   ├── Behaviors
│   │   │   └── ValidationBehavior.cs
│   │   ├── DTOs
│   │   │   └── Requests
│   │   │       └── PaymentRequestDto.cs
│   │   ├── Exceptions
│   │   │   └── ValidationException.cs
│   │   ├── Extensions
│   │   │   └── ServiceConfiguration.cs
│   │   ├── Features
│   │   │   └── Payment
│   │   │       ├── Commands
│   │   │       │   ├── SendToPaymentProvider
│   │   │       │   │   ├── SendToPaymentProviderCommand.cs
│   │   │       │   │   ├── SendToPaymentProviderCommandHandler.cs
│   │   │       │   │   └── SendToPaymentProviderCommandValidator.cs
│   │   │       │   └── Void
│   │   │       └── Queries
│   │   ├── Interfaces
│   │   │   ├── Application
│   │   │   │   └── Services
│   │   │   │       └── Payment
│   │   │   │           └── IPaymentProvider.cs
│   │   │   └── Infrastructure
│   │   │       └── PaymentProvider
│   │   │           └── Strategies
│   │   │               └── Payment
│   │   │                   └── IPaymentSendingContext.cs
│   │   ├── Models
│   │   │   └── Payment
│   │   │       └── CreditCardDetail.cs
│   │   └── Services     
│   └── Domain.csproj
│       ├── Common
│       │   └── BaseEntity.cs
│       ├── Constants
│       │   └── ExceptionMessages.cs
│       ├── DomainEvents
│       │   └── PaymentAdded.cs
│       ├── Entities
│       │   └── Payment.cs
│       ├── Exceptions
│       │   └── NotFoundException.cs
│       ├── LookupValues
│       │   ├── LvBank.cs
│       │   └── LvPaymentType.cs
│       ├── Repositories
│       │   └── IPaymentRepository.cs
│       ├── UnitOfWork
│       │   └── IUnitOfWork.cs
│       └── ValueObjects
├── Infrastructure
│   ├── Infrastructure.csproj
│   │   ├── Extensions
│   │   │   └── ServiceConfiguration.cs
│   │   ├── PaymentProvider
│   │   │   ├── Interfaces
│   │   │   │   └── AllowedPaymentMethods
│   │   │   │       └── ICreditCardAllowed.cs 
│   │   │   ├── Models
│   │   │   │   └── PaymentRequests
│   │   │   │       ├── BankOneCreditCardPaymentRequest.cs
│   │   │   │       └── BankTwoCheckPaymentRequest.cs
│   │   │   └── Strategies
│   │   │       └── Payment
│   │   │           ├── BankOnePaymentSendingStrategy.cs
│   │   │           ├── BankTwoPaymentSendingStrategy.cs
│   │   │           └── PaymentSendingContext.cs
│   │   └── SecretsManagement
│   │       ├── Interfaces
│   │       │   └── IAzureKeyVaultServices.cs
│   │       ├── Models
│   │       │   ├── Configurations
│   │       │   │   └── KeyVaultConfiguration.cs
│   │       │   └── Secrets
│   │       │       └── AzureKeyVaultSecret.cs
│   │       ├── Providers
│   │       │   └── SecretClientProvider.cs
│   │       └── Services
│   │           └── AzureKeyVaultServices
│   └── Persistence.csproj
│       ├── Contexts
│       │   └── AppDbContext.cs
│       ├── EntityConfigurations
│       │   └── PaymentConfiguration.cs
│       ├── Extensions
│       │   └── ServiceConfigurations.cs
│       ├── LookupValueConfigurations
│       │   ├── LvBankConfiguration.cs
│       │   └── LvPaymentTypeConfiguration.cs
│       ├── Models
│       │   └── AppSettingConfiguration
│       │       └── DbConnectionString.cs
│       ├── Repositories
│       │   └── PaymentRepository.cs
│       └── UnitOfWork 
│           └── UnitOfWork.cs
└── Presentation
    └── Api.csproj
        ├── Configurations
        │   ├── ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs
        │   └── ApiVersionConfiguration.cs
        ├── Controllers
        │   └── PaymentController.cs
        └── Extensions
            ├── MigrationManager.cs
            └── ServiceConfigurations.cs
Tests
├── Core
│   └── Application.UnitTest.csproj
│       ├── Features
│       └── Services
└── Infrastructure
    ├── Infrastructure.UnitTest.csproj
    └── Persistence.UnitTest.csproj

